# WHy custom plugin slows down the loading of the pages?

Tags: plugins, php

I created 5 custom plugins, that comunicates with Apigee. (create developers, delete accounts, create apps). I wanted to combine all in one folder, so I created a loader.php file:

```
 <?php
/*
Plugin Name: Apigee
Description: Contains plugin CreateDev, plugin CreateDevApp, plugin 
DeleteAccount, plugin GetApIProducts and plugin GetDevApps
*/

require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'CreateDev.php';
require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'CreateDevApp.php';
require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'DeleteAccount.php';
require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'GetApIProducts.php';
require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'GetDevApps.php';
?>
```

After I activate the plugin everything works as expected, but the pages load really slow(something that did not happen before). Furthermore if this plugin is activated I am not able to upload media files.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

```
function myplugin_develoepr_registration(){
$post_url=
'https://api.enterprise....developers';

 $arg_data = array('email'=> $_POST['user_email'],  "firstName" 
 =>$_POST['first_name'], "lastName" => $_POST['last_name'] , "userName" =>  
 $_POST['user_login']  );
  $data = json_encode( $arg_data );

$args = array('headers'=> array('Content-Type'=>'application/json', 
'Authorization' => 'Basic XXX'),'body'=> $data );

 $response = wp_remote_post( esc_url_raw( $post_url ), $args );
 $response_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response );
 $response_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );

 print_r($_POST['user_email']);
 print_r($_POST['first_name']);
 print_r($_POST['last_name']);
print_r( $_POST['user_login'] );

if(!in_array( $response_code, array(200,201))|| is_wp_error( $response_body 
))

returnfalse;
 }

 add_action('user_register','myplugin_develoepr_registration')

 ?>
```

Comment: Give us some code of your plugin, specially what happen on 'init' hook.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: The slow happens on all page, or only when `user_register` hook is triggered ?

Comment: All page! the website is slow at all.

Comment: Is there function in your required files that launch an API call without hook, or in another hook ? I think there is an action performed in a general hook like `init` or `pre_get_posts` for example. https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/ this plugin add a debug bar in your admin bar. You can find the hook, the API calls with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think no one will give you exact answer why your code is slow. The thing is we don't know what is inside each file. You have to profile your code. Simplest way to profile code is to use `microtime`.

```
$time = -microtime(true); 

// Here exeute code which you want to profile

$time += microtime(true); 

echo sprintf('Your code executed in in %fs', $time) . '<br>';

exit;
```

I would first profile each `require` and see which takes the most time to load. This can look something like that.

```
$format = 'File %s required in %fs';

$require_plugin_file = function( $file ) use ($format) {

    $time = -microtime(true);

    require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . $file;

    $time += microtime(true); 

    echo sprintf($format, $file, $time) . '<br>';
};

$require_plugin_file('file1.php');
$require_plugin_file('file2.php');
$require_plugin_file('file3.php');
$require_plugin_file('file4.php');
$require_plugin_file('file5.php');

exit;
```

Output of this could be:

```
File file1.php required in 0.000260s
File file2.php required in 0.000255s
File file3.php required in 3.000257s
File file4.php required in 0.000241s
File file5.php required in 0.000235s
```

Now I know that my `file3.php` take the most time to load and I would see in this file where the problem is.

Note: In sample code I'm using `Anonymous functions` which are available from `php 5.4`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this example! Smll question, do I need to profile in separate file or I can do it in the load.php i created?

Comment: First try to profile in general, single load.php and if you find that this file is causing problem open it and profile separate file after that profile in parts your code. E.g. only function1 and then function2 and then function3